# Can't create ReplicationController for Nginx in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, dashboard, kubectl, docker-ingress

Want to create a `ingress controller` for k8s. Use nginx ingress sample to do it.

Follow this created `nginx-rc.yaml` file:

https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/proxy-protocol/nginx-rc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  labels:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
        name: nginx-ingress-lb
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3
        name: nginx-ingress-lb
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        # use downward API
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
        - --nginx-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller
```

After created it then k8s shows:

[image]

Check from console:

```
$ kubectl describe pod nginx-ingress-controller-5wxch
Name:           nginx-ingress-controller-5wxch
Namespace:      default
Node:           minikube/192.168.99.100
Start Time:     Fri, 17 Nov 2017 15:50:33 +0900
Labels:         k8s-app=nginx-ingress-lb
                name=nginx-ingress-lb
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicationController","namespace":"default","name":"nginx-ingress-controller","uid":"9c1aba15-cb63-11e7-9...
Status:         Running
IP:             172.17.0.15
Created By:     ReplicationController/nginx-ingress-controller
Controlled By:  ReplicationController/nginx-ingress-controller
Containers:
  nginx-ingress-lb:
    Container ID:  docker://9fabc8d7f74b442c35ac5f443e7f35117b183e61aa37851dfdb5847d90252672
    Image:         gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller@sha256:820c338dc22eda7ab6331001da3cccd43b1b7dcd179049d33a62ad6deaef8daf
    Ports:         80/TCP, 443/TCP
    Args:
      /nginx-ingress-controller
      --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
      --nginx-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-controller
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    255
      Started:      Fri, 17 Nov 2017 15:52:43 +0900
      Finished:     Fri, 17 Nov 2017 15:52:43 +0900
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  4
    Liveness:       http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:10254/healthz delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POD_NAME:       nginx-ingress-controller-5wxch (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:  default (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-0nlh9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  default-token-0nlh9:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-0nlh9
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age               From               Message
  ----     ------                 ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled              3m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned nginx-ingress-controller-5wxch to minikube
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  3m                kubelet, minikube  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-0nlh9"
  Warning  Unhealthy              2m                kubelet, minikube  Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.17.0.15:10254/healthz: dial tcp 172.17.0.15:10254: getsockopt: connection refused
  Normal   Pulling                1m (x5 over 3m)   kubelet, minikube  pulling image "gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3"
  Normal   Pulled                 1m (x5 over 2m)   kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3"
  Normal   Created                1m (x5 over 2m)   kubelet, minikube  Created container
  Normal   Started                1m (x5 over 2m)   kubelet, minikube  Started container
  Warning  BackOff                0s (x17 over 2m)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  FailedSync             0s (x17 over 2m)  kubelet, minikube  Error syncing pod
```

Now using minikube on Mac. The kubernetes version is:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.2", GitCommit:"bdaeafa71f6c7c04636251031f93464384d54963", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-24T19:48:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.5", GitCommit:"17d7182a7ccbb167074be7a87f0a68bd00d58d97", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-10-06T20:53:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

So what's the reason? Does this version can't support the config file, or the config file has outdated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information with `kubectl describe pod xxx`, as you did.
And more information with `kubectl get pod xxx -o yaml` (this pretty much gives you everything the cluster knows about the pod).
And finally, check the pod's logs with `kubect logs xxx`.

When I reproduce with your manifest yaml file, `kubectl get pod xxx` shows:

`kubectl logs nginx-ingress-controller-test-4mgw7

I1117 08:44:11.650301       1 main.go:94] Using build: https://github.com/bprashanth/contrib.git - git-92b2bac
F1117 08:44:11.703533       1 main.go:121] no service with name default/default-http-backend found: services "default-http-backend" not found`

So there you go, you're missing a backend service.

Tip: an easier way to install the ingress nginx controler could be:

`helm install ing-nginx-ctrl stable/nginx-ingress`

There's an helm chart for it.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reproduce and very detail answer! Use helm is easy to do.